# how to disable web deploying azure functions from users with user-level credentials

Tags: yaml, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

Trying to enforce that only an app can deploy changes to our team's azure functions so I want to disable a user from being able to web deploy changes.

Background:
The deploy app is triggered in a build pipeline, once changes have been signed off in code review.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways

**WAY - 1**
You can choose Reader in order to make the user not to have certain permissions. To set RBAC rules for certain users.

For assigning the role for resource scope you can directly do it from azure portal itself. This is the procedure that you can follow.

[image]

1. Select the resource that you want to assign.
2. Under  **Manage**, select  **Roles**   to see the list of roles for Azure resources.

[image]

3. Select a member or group you want to assign to the role **(READER)** and then click  **Select**.

[image]

For more information you can refer it from [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/pim-resource-roles-assign-roles#role-assignment-conditions).

---

**WAY - 2**
Add permissions for the users in Azure pipeline.

1. From within your project, select  **Pipelines**  >  **Pipelines**. Select the  **All**  tab, and then select the more actions menu then  **Manage security**.

   [image: Manage pipeline security]
2. On the permissions dialog box, make sure the following  Role (READER)  permissions are set to Allow.

For more information you can refer [Pipelines user permissions - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/set-permissions?view=azure-devops)